# Relaying a stream from OBS to multiple sites at once

Tags: windows, redirection, rtmp, relay

I've searching a lot about this on OBS Studio forums, but the only answer I've got was: *"Use restream.io"*.
The problem is restream charges for Facebook relay, and I can't rent this service at this time.

Searching more I've found some responses talking about RTMP and NGINX, but I don't use Linux on my second computer (Windows 10 x64).

I also saw [some RTMP packets on node](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/rtmp) but most of them are libraries rather than CLI apps, and I'm short of time to code in JavaScript, so what are my alternatives to relay my stream to various sites at once?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution I can think of, if you're not opposed to working with NGINX, is to utilise cygwin to run NGINX on your windows pc. To make it a usable RTMP server, you can follow the guide at this link:
https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/174603-how-to-live-stream-to-multiple-services-with-a-rtmp-server/

Another possible idea is, if you can afford the extra cpu usage, to use one instance of OBS with restream.io and a second instance of OBS specifically for facebook.

Answer (score -1):

The best way will be to use FFmpeg, you can provide multiple outputs in FFmpeg by using this method you can stream to multiple sites. 
There is also one other free alternative for restream to [stream to multiple sites](https://castr.io) you can use [Castr.io](http://www.castr.io) which is free to restream to facebook.

Comment: Please provide a complete, self-contained answer; don't just link to it.